# How to pack individual class fies in a jar artifact in intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea

In Intellij IDEA 14

I want to pack 2 classes in a jar file and not the whole module. If I make an artifact it includes everything.

I want to have an artifact replace the following command:

```
java -jar custom.jar com.xx.class1.class com.xx.class2.class
```

Comment: I don't know if this is possible with IntelliJ.  But in general, if you want to do anything remotely non-standard in terms of building artifacts, you should consider using a proper build tool (e.g. Gradle).

Comment: yes I know, it's just overkill since it's a one line command. I just wanted to include it in the project settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of IntelliJ IDEA 14, this is not possible. You can move those two classes to a separate module and set up an artifact for the compilation output of that module.